# Parse and remove parts of strings between delimiters

Tags: shell, cygwin, regex, sed

I would like to go through a file and remove certain sequences in between delimiters.

For example

```
 drw---- 00000000 11111111        0 ./a/
 drw---- 00000000 11111111        0 ./b/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./c/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./d/k/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./e/l/r/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./f/m/s/x/
 ------- 00000000 11111111       89 ./g/n/t/y/C.xml
 dr----- 00000000 11111111        0 ./h/o/u/z/
 dr-r--- 00000000 11111111        0 ./i/p/v/A/D/
 d--r--- 00000000 11111111        0 ./j/q/w/B/
```

Would become

```
 drw---- ./a/
 drw---- ./b/
 d------ ./c/
 d------ ./d/k/
 d------ ./e/l/r/
 d------ ./f/m/s/x/
 ------- ./g/n/t/y/C.xml
 dr----- ./h/o/u/z/
 dr-r--- ./i/p/v/A/D/
 d--r--- ./j/q/w/B/
```

Where the starting delimiter is the 2nd space in the file, and the ending delimiter is ./

I'm really new to cygwin and all of it's clever tools, so I have no idea what to do. I'm pretty sure I could use sed and regular expressions somehow, but I simply don't know enough to come up with the solution on my own.

Comment: delimiter <-- that is how you spell it. You got  it right elsewhere but not in the subject.  The word limit is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is using `awk`.

```
$ awk '{print $1, $5}' myfile.txt
```

`awk` reads the file line by line, sets some special variables and runs the command for each line. `$1` and `$5` here contain first and fifth string when a line is tokenized by using space as delimeter.

Comment: Damn this is a nice solution, thanks so much. I'll have to read up on GAWK, seems like it's very useful.

Comment: unless any filename has spaces. Then you might want to say `awk '{$2=$3=$4=""; print}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex you want. Either open the file in vim and run it, or do `sed the_expression oldname > newname`.

`:%s/[0-9][0-9]*//g`

Explanation:
The % symbol specifies that the following command should be run on the whole file.
`s` means `search/for this expression/and replace it with this one/`
In your case you want to delete all the numbers so we instruct vim's regex engine to search for every occurrence of one or more number and replace it with nothing.

Comment: This is a very good solution as well, gawk is a little simpler though if you're not that familiar with regex

Comment: that one is just removing numbers not actually removing that which is between the "delimiters". In the example he gives it'd work as its numbers between the delimiters.  What he meant is another matter.

Comment: @barlop I know, this was a quick and dirty solution for the data at hand.

Answer (score 1):

"Where the starting delimiter is the 2nd space in the file, and the ending delimiter is ./"

Here's an  ugly one just for you

```
C:\sdf>type p.p
 drw---- 00000000 11111111        0 ./a/
 drw---- 00000000 11111111        0 ./b/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./c/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./d/k/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./e/l/r/
 d------ 00000000 11111111        0 ./f/m/s/x/
 ------- 00000000 11111111       89 ./g/n/t/y/C.xml
 dr----- 00000000 11111111        0 ./h/o/u/z/
 dr-r--- 00000000 11111111        0 ./i/p/v/A/D/
 d--r--- 00000000 11111111        0 ./j/q/w/B/
C:\sdf>sed -r "s/(\s+\S+\s*)([^.]*\.\/)/\1.\//" p.p
 drw---- ./a/
 drw---- ./b/
 d------ ./c/
 d------ ./d/k/
 d------ ./e/l/r/
 d------ ./f/m/s/x/
 ------- ./g/n/t/y/C.xml
 dr----- ./h/o/u/z/
 dr-r--- ./i/p/v/A/D/
 d--r--- ./j/q/w/B/
C:\sdf>
```